# Suppose $f(x) = x^5 + 2x^4 − x^3 + 3x^2 + 5x + 1$. Find a polynomial $g$ of degree $2$ or less such that $f(x) \equiv g(x) \pmod 3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $f(x) = x^5 + 2x^4 − x^3 + 3x^2 + 5x + 1$. Find a polynomial $g$ of degree $2$ or less such that $f(x) \equiv g(x) \pmod 3$.

Comment: Note that $(-1)^2=1$, $1^2=1$, $0^2=0$. What is $x^3$?

Comment: $$  \left(   x^{5}  + 2 x^{4}  -  x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  + 5 x  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  -  x  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  \right) } +  \left(  5 x^{2}  + 5 x  + 1 \right)  $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By employing Fermat's little theorem: $x^3 = x\pmod 3\implies x^5=x^3=x\pmod 3, 2x^4 = 2x^2\pmod 3, -x^3=-x\pmod 3\implies x^5+2x^4-x^3=x+2x^2-x=2x^2\pmod 3$. Thus we can take $g(x) = 2x^2+3x^2+5x+1= 5x^2+5x+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply Fermat's little theorem, $x^3 \equiv x \pmod 3$. Also any term with a coefficient that's a multiple of $3$ will vanish modulo $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=ax^2 +bx +c$

Then $f(x) =x^5 + 2x^4 -x^3 +3x^2 + 5x + 1\equiv$

$x^5 -x^4 -x^3-x+1\equiv ax^2 + bx + c\pmod 3$.

Which means

If $x \equiv 0\pmod 3$

Then $1 \equiv c\pmod 3$.

If $x \equiv 1$

then $2\equiv a+b +c \equiv a+b + 1$ so $a+b\equiv 1$.

And if $x\equiv -1$ then

$-1-1+1+1+1 \equiv a-b + c \equiv a-b +1$ so $a-b\equiv 0\pmod 3$

So $a\equiv b$ and $a+b\equiv 2a \equiv -a \equiv 1\pmod 3$ so $a \equiv b \equiv -1\pmod 3$ and $c\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

So we can have $-x^2-x + 1$ or any other coefficients where $a,b,c \equiv -1,-1,c$.

....

One thing to not.

If $g(x) = -x^2 -x^2 +1$ then $f(x) -g(x) = x^5 + 2x^4 -x^3 +4x^2 + 6x =$

$x(x^4 +2x^3 -x^2 +4x + 6)=$

$x^2(x^3+2x^2 - x + 4) +6=$

$x^2(x^2(x-1)+3x^2 -x +4) +6=$

$x^2(x^2(x-1) + 3x(x-1) + 2x + 4) + 6=$

$x^2(x^2(x-1)+3x(x-1) + 2(x-1) + 6) + 6=$

$x^2(x-1)(x^2 + 3x + 2) + 6x^2 + 6 =$

$x^2(x-1)(x+1)(x+2) + (6x^2 + 6)$.

For $f(x)-g(x)$ to be equiv $0$ for all $x\in \mathbb Z$ then $x,x-1,x+1$ must be roots, plus or minus polynomial multiple of $3$.  And that is exactly the case here.

....

we could have solved it from the get go by synthetically dividing but $x(x+1)(x-1) = x^3 - x$. and taking the negative of the remainder.

$x^5 + 2x^4 -x^3 + 3x^2 + 5x + 1 =$

$x^2(x^3-x) +2x^4 +3x^2 + 5x +1=$

$x^2(x^3 -x) + 2x(x^3 - x) + 5x^2 + 5x + 1=$

So $5x^2 + 5x + 1 \equiv -x^2 -x +1\pmod 3$ would work.